# Cannot remotely debug with PHPStorm built-in server and Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, phpstorm

I am trying to remotely debug my web app in PHPStorm built-in web server (port 63342, sometimes 63343). I have tried both USB adb in Chrome as well as wifi. All to no avail.

I have Android Studio installed and read this [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging).

I still cannot access my page.

On **USB/adb**
At `chrome://inspect` - I defined a port forwarding item:

`8080` > `http://192.168.1.100:63342/<projectname>/index.html`.

192.168.1.100 being my laptop IP. The communication between devices is ok - tabs close and open - but the page never completes loading `(ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)`.

On **wifi**, having enabled my Android IP on my router's firewall - a similar effect - page never loads.

Is the PHPStorm built-in server special in any way that could prevent me from remote testing? What should I observe to make the setup finally work?

Comment: By default the `63342` port accepts local connections only. You need to enable such option and restart IDE. See if this will make any better (because when I was trying to serve php files this way it did not worked at all, even if accessing from local interface -- possibly my OS/environment specific settings).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it did not any better, although it was good to become aware of this option.

Comment: Moreover, I noticed that hitting laptop's own IP (`http://192.168.1.100:63342/<projectname>/index.html`) also yields an error. Is this normal?

Comment: I think not -- I had exactly the same. Try with domain name (fake it via your local `hosts` file) instead of IP in URL.

Comment: Still no go. The amount of unsuccessful attempts at various points makes me think there's something wrong with my win settings (8.1)